# md5 hashes are different with iso-images of 14.04 amd64 server and desktop

Tags: 14.04, hash

What shall I care for?
Are sums given at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes wrong?
Or do used progs calculate wrong?

```
description/Source                                  md5-hash
WinMD5Sum: ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso          ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9
WinMD5Sum: ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso         119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd
UbuntuSite hash: ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso      01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c 
UbuntuSite hash: ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso     dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 
fileVerifier++: ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso     ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9
fileVerifier++: ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso    119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd
```

As you may see, WinMD5Sum and fileVerifier++ calculate the same value, but different from values shown at above mentioned site.

Answer (score 3):

The MD5 hashes for the Ubuntu 14.04 iso from the [Ubuntu Hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) website that you linked in your question were lasted edited on 2014-04-18 22:44:22. Since then an updated Ubuntu 14.04.1 point release has been released that has different iso files with different iso file names and different MD5 hashes as you can see in the below text block. The [MD5SUMS for the Ubuntu 14.04.1 release](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/MD5SUMS) are as follows:

```
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
08d25bf879e353686a974b7b14ae7d81 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso
119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
a4fc15313ef2a516bfbf83ce44281535 *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9 *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
3aa14ca13d52df070870d39306f4a4eb *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso
b31731ea6cdbebe1d02f8193db420886 *wubi.exe
```

This shows that the MD5 hashes that you got from  WinMD5Sum and fileVerifier++ are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look for the hashes are at the [repository](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS) itself. The page you linked to is community maintained and maybe a bit out of date.

The MD5SUMS file reproduced here for convenience:

```
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
08d25bf879e353686a974b7b14ae7d81 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso
119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
a4fc15313ef2a516bfbf83ce44281535 *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9 *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
3aa14ca13d52df070870d39306f4a4eb *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso
b31731ea6cdbebe1d02f8193db420886 *wubi.exe
```

As you can see, that hashes you got for the 14.04.1 images are correct.

Comment: @karel sorry about that. I was on the app and formatting the hashes for took me the best part of ten minutes. When i started answering the question was only 3 minutes old. +1 to you.