# I am not able to find the md5sum for ubuntu 14.04.1 iso image

Tags: md5sum

I have just downloaded the new release of ubuntu which is ubuntu 14.04.1. but i am unable to find the md5sum for this. the ubuntu website show me the md5sums of ubuntu 14.04 and more previous versions. so how to find the md5sum for ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso?

Comment: possible duplicate of [md5 hashes are different with iso-images of 14.04 amd64 server and desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520243/md5-hashes-are-different-with-iso-images-of-14-04-amd64-server-and-desktop)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes#A14.04_LTS

Answer (score 0):

md5sum for all Ubuntu 14.04.x is as following:

```
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
08d25bf879e353686a974b7b14ae7d81 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso
119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
a4fc15313ef2a516bfbf83ce44281535 *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9 *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
3aa14ca13d52df070870d39306f4a4eb *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso
b31731ea6cdbebe1d02f8193db420886 *wubi.exe
```

[How to md5sum?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

source: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/MD5SUMS

Comment: the md5sum is the same :)